# how to get tap location from UIScrollview that covered by UITextview

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview, location, uitextview, tap

HI all...

i have a textview as a subview of scrollview, the textview is cover all of scrollview area.
i want to get location tap in scrollview, but the textview didn't passed it
the case is, if i tap the textview, the tap is also detected in scrollview.
can i do that?

this is my implementation :

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{   
UIGestureRecognizer *tapScroll = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTap:)];
//tapScroll.numberOfTapsRequired = 2;
[self.scrollView addGestureRecognizer:tapScroll];

self.tapGesture = (UITapGestureRecognizer *)tapScroll;
tapScroll.delegate = self;

[tapScroll release];
```

}

```
-(void)handleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer{
NSLog(@"handle tap");
location = [recognizer locationInView:self.scrollView];

[self.textView becomeFirstResponder];

NSLog(@"location tap x : %f, y : %f", location.x, location.y);


if (location.y < self.view.frame.size.height - keyBoardBounds.size.height) {
    NSLog(@"HEIGHT : %f", self.view.frame.size.height - keyBoardBounds.size.height);
    [self.scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointZero animated:YES];    
}else {
    [self.scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, location.y/2) animated:YES];
}
```

}

i can't get the tap location, because the textview didn't passed it, can somebody help me, please??

Answer (score 0):

Subclass the UITextView and override

```
- (BOOL)touchesShouldBegin:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event inContentView:(UIView *)view
```

Tutorial [here](http://flux88.com/blog/detecting-a-tap-on-a-uitextview/)

Comment: i have do that, but the textview still didn't pass the gesture, can u tell me how?